# Apache HttpClient 4 And JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, apache-commons-httpclient

I Use Apache HttpClient to Access a webpage . i want to click on a link but the link is javaScript , how can i process click on a javascript link and follow url redirection ?

sample javascript and html code :

```
<a href="javascript:send(32023, 'YGHN_JKM', '8LMK');"> link</a>


function send(content_id, fic, cgRate) {
        var params = new Hash();
        params.set('content_id', content_id);
        params.set('tool', fic);
        params.set('cgRate', cgRate);

        new Ajax.Updater('return', '/mypkg/tools', {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: params,
            evalScripts: true,
            onInitialize: new Effect.Appear('loader', {duration: 0.0}),
            onComplete: new Effect.Fade('loader', {duration: 1.2})
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this a Java question?  http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/  Or are you screen scraping?

Comment: I think this is a java question ! if u think it's not ! this is your opinion . thank you.

Comment: So... it sounds like you're loading a page with JavaScript links on it using Apache HttpClient. You want to programmatically click the JavaScript links and "follow" them with your application?

Comment: Yes , Exactly i want to programmatically click the JavaScript links and "follow" them with my application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the page you are trying to get to uses AJAX to fetch the link. It would be difficult to emulate this behavior with just vanilla HTTPClient. HTTPClient is for "raw" HTTP communication, and not browser emulation. Instead, I recommend using something akin to HtmlUnit, which can emulate a browser and execute the JavaScript on the page: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

HtmlUnit has rather good JavaScript support, but it is not perfect. If you need to rely on 100% perfect browser emulation, you need to use a browser automation framework such as Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thanks, i use Jsoup for parsing html. I test htmlUnit and told you result. can u give me a list of browser automation framework or tell which of them are best . Thank you

Comment: Try HtmlUnit first to see if it does what you need. If it doesn't work, then you don't have alternatives beyond Selenium, but that's a heavier solution (it uses an instance of a real browser) and may or may not work for your particular use case.