# Need to get table data using httpclient

Tags: java, ajax, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using following code to get pagecontent. But unfortunately i'm not able to get data which is within the table.

```
HttpGet httget = new HttpGet("http://pstweb.cloudapp.net/raselect/?tid=188J"); 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpResponse  response = httpclient.execute(httget); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
String thirdPartyPageContent=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

But if you enter the url directly in browser I get all the data in table. My understanding is to make ajax call it takes some time. But our httpclient is not waiting for the same. 
please help me in getting the table page content. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table-data is retrieved via an ajax-call I don't think `HttpClient` will help you much. To process ajax-calls your client has to execute all Javascript-commands and `HttpClient` will not do it since it is just a http client. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260282/apache-httpclient-4-and-javascript) for further hints.