# httpclient can't handle URL redirection?

Tags: java, redirect, apache-httpclient-4.x

I’m using HTTPClient 4.3.5 version but looks like httpclient can’t handle url redirect.
In browser if I add this below URL

http://www.graybar.com/store/SearchDisplay?categoryId=&storeId=11751&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView=&beginIndex=0&pageSize=15&searchType=100&orderBy=5&searchTerm=25062903

It is getting redirected to
http://www.graybar.com/store/en/gb/hubbell-pro-2-pole-15a-125v-heavy-duty-5-15r-duplex-receptacle-smooth-face-25062903

But in HTTPclient I get 200 ok but the pagecontent is not matching to the above 2nd URL.
Below is my code. Kindly help me how to get the 2nd page content.

```
HttpEntity entity=null;
                 HttpGet httpget=null;
                 HttpResponse  response=null;

                 HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();

                 httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.graybar.com/store/SearchDisplay?categoryId=&storeId=11751&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView=&beginIndex=0&pageSize=15&searchType=100&orderBy=5&searchTerm=25062903");
           httpget.setHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2");
           response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
           entity = response.getEntity();

                 String thirdPartyPageContent=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                 System.out.println(thirdPartyPageContent);
```

Answer (score 2):

The page content returned by the first URL contains javascript. Parts of this javascript is executed by the browser when the page is loaded (onload). This part requests a different page from the server and hence overwrite the page loaded by the first url. As HttpClient doesn't interpret or execute the javascript, it doesn't reload the page.

A proper http redirect is indicated by the server returning code 301 or 302. HttpClient can follow those redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain the scenario how to handle httpclient for this case?

Comment: @SandeshPuttaraj You can hava a look at selenium, httpunit or other solutions, as mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260282/apache-httpclient-4-and-javascript